# How does getline() actually behave?

Tags: c++

I have 2 questions:

1. What happens to s if I again do a "getline(in,line)" after the while loop ends?

   ```
   ifstream in("string.txt");
   string s, line;
   s = "";
   while(getline(in,line))
   {

       s = s + line + "\n";

   }

   cout<<s<<endl<<"******************************************"<<endl;
   ```
2. The getline() function: everytime it is called, does it goes to the "next" line of the ifstream "in" object in the above code? If so what happens when the while loop ends and I call the same function again? (almost the same as first question, just a subtle difference)

Comment: Your questions are not very clear.  Try reading the reference documentation for getline.  If you're still confused, try wording your question more carefully.  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/getline/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What happens to s if I again do a "getline(in,line)" after the while loop ends?

The loop ends when `std::getline()` returns something that resembles a boolean `false`. When you look at the signature of the function you will see that it returns the stream. Streams have an implicit conversion to something boolean-like that resembles their state. If `if(stream)` evaluates the stream to `false`, then that means that the stream is in a bad state. This could be the EOF flag set or one of the error flags, or both.
Any attempt to use a stream that is in a bad state will fail. Nothing will be read.

> The getline() function: everytime it is called, does it goes to the "next" line of the ifstream "in" object in the above code? If so what happens when the while loop ends and I call the same function again? (almost the same as first question, just a subtle difference)

This has nothing to do with `std::getline()`. The position in the opened file is a property of the (file) stream. Every time you (re-)open the file for reading (without passing extra parameter for setting the position), the position is set to the beginning of the stream (file).

Comment: Nitpick: `std::basic_ios::operator bool` is `explicit`, but the language allows implicit uses of `explicit operator bool` in statements like these.

Comment: @Caleth: A decade ago there were no explicit implicit conversion operators yet.

Answer (score 0):

`getline` reads the stream until it encounters the newline character or reaches the end of stream. In latter case, the steam will have its failbit set. This translates to breaking the `while` loop in your example, because `getline` returns the (reference to) stream which is get cast to `bool`, yielding stream's state that is `false` because of aforementioned failbit.

In such conditions, subsequent calls to `getline` will do nothing as the stream is still in the 'fail' state. You could clear it with `istream::clear`, but since there is no more data in it, it have its failbit set again on next read.

Comment: It will not have the fail bit set on encountering the end of stream. It will have its eof bit set after the **next** call to getline(). The EOF is not set until you read **PAST** the end of file, the last successful read will read up-to the end of file but not past.